# Как убрать ненужный текст из логов?

Tags: python, логирование

Работаю с модулем `logging`. Вывожу текст в виджет PyQt. При подключении Discord-бота, выводится текст, ну который я вовсе не жду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это я ещё режим `logging`, поставил на `INFO`. При `DEBUG`, выводилось больше текста.

```
logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: привидите пример что должно получиться. какая инфа нужна а какая нет ?

Comment: @Интик, нужно, чтобы этот текст вовсе не выводился. Именно при подключении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понял до конца проблему, поскольку не понятно, что должно выводиться в виджет, но debug самый низкий уровень вывода. Может стоит повысить уровень логгера?

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: И потом выводить текст `logging.warning(msg)`?

Comment: Не понятно, что за текст выводится и его назначение, но да можно logging.warning() или logging.error()

Comment: Этот текст выводится при включение Discord - бота. Даже в логах он обозначен как: `discord.client`,
`discord.gateway`, `discord.http`. Просто неизвестно, почему он выводится в виджет PyQt. Поэтому задал вопрос, как от этого избавиться.